# LEFT JOIN com mais de uma condição no ON - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Oi, Gente, tudo bem?

Estou montando uma query, e preciso fazer um join.
No caso, os registros da tabela AIV têm uma data de início e pode ou não ter uma data fim.
Eu quero que elas se cruzem da seguinte forma:

1 - Se a data fim da tabela AIV estiver nula, a data da tabela CPC deve ser maior que a data início da AIV;

2 - Se a data fim tabela AIV não estiver nula, a data da tabela CPC deve estar entre a data início e data fim da AIV;

Acontece que quando eu tento escrever dessa forma:

```
LEFT JOIN ApontamentoImpactoVigencia AIV ON 
                                    AIV.AssuntoId = AA.AssuntoId 
                                    AND 
                                    IIF(AIV.Fim_Data IS NOT NULL, (CPC.Data between AIV.Inicio_Data and AIV.Fim_Data), CPC.Data >= AIV.Inicio_Data)
```

Ele apresenta erro, não aceitando o "between" e nem o sinal de >=

Se eu tento fazer destas maneiras:

```
LEFT JOIN ApontamentoImpactoVigencia AIV ON 
                                AIV.AssuntoId = AA.AssuntoId 
                                AND 
                                CPC.Data >= AIV.Inicio_Data
```

E

```
LEFT JOIN ApontamentoImpactoVigencia AIV ON 
                                AIV.AssuntoId = AA.AssuntoId 
                                AND 
                                CPC.Data between AIV.Inicio_Data and AIV.Fim_Data
```

O SQL Server aceita (mas daí não atende ao critério que preciso).
Portanto, o erro não está no "between" nem no sinal de ">=".....
Ou seja, tem algo a ver com o IIF.

**(Com CASE WHEN acontece a mesma coisa)**

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como resolver isso ???
Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa noite,

Acho que da forma como você colocou não vai funcionar pois o IIF espera um valor para quando a condição é verdadeira e outro para quando não é, e não uma outra condição. E o mesmo vale para o Case.
Segue uma sugestão para teste utilizando a função Coalesce para alterar o valor final do between se a data final for nula:

```
LEFT JOIN ApontamentoImpactoVigencia AIV ON 
    AIV.AssuntoId = AA.AssuntoId 
    AND 
    CPC.Data between AIV.Inicio_Data and coalesce(AIV.Fim_Data, CPC.Data)
```

**Edit:** alternativa tradicional

```
LEFT JOIN ApontamentoImpactoVigencia AIV ON 
    AIV.AssuntoId = AA.AssuntoId 
    AND 
    (
      CPC.Data >= AIV.Inicio_Data and 
      (
         CPC.Data <= AIV.Fim_Data or
         AIV.Fim_Data is null
      )
    )
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: Vou tentar, obrigada

Comment: Vc conseguiu fazer o teste? Funcionou? Estou editando a resposta para acrescentar uma alternativa talvez mais tradicional

Comment: consegui sim, deu certo!